# Mac cannot read mp3 audio cd

Tags: audio, homebrew, mp3

I recently purchased a mp3 audio cd thinking I could play it on my Mac. I get this 'unreadable disk' message when I insert the CD into my external DVD drive:" [image: Screenshot of error dialog] The only thing I've done so far is to install FFMPEG (`brew install ffmpeg`). This had no effect. I have no idea what the problem is. The DVD drive seems to be fine. It reads DVD disks OK.  I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It's an audio CD, or it's a Joliet/ISO9660 CD with MP3 files on it?

Comment: Why would you think *[FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/)* would fix a non-readable disk medium?  This is like saying you bought premium gas because you couldn't get your car to recognize the keyfob that opens the boot lid.  Can you post an image of the CD Jewel case and of the CD itself?

Comment: On a very basic level it sounds like the disc might be damaged/defective, hence that error message. Or it could be in an unreadable format. You could check for scratches on the disc or try the disc in another computer. Failing that return the CD and get another copy.